# Should we close questions in any other language than English?

Tags: discussion, scope

I personally have nothing against questions in other languages, but a flag on a Spanish-language question just came. The flag says "wrong language".

What do you all think?

Answer (score 3):

As with most SE sites, SoftwareRecs is run in English. And as our sister sites do, we should stick to that – and close non-English questions as "unclear what you're asking". As far as I understand, that's what the standard on SE is. Additional reasons:

- we already have our load of off-topic and low-quality questions. Plus a bunch in the grey area. Allowing foreign languages would not help improving quality: if you allow one, you cannot forbid others.
- with some languages being "broadly understood" (English, French, Spain, Portuguese – maybe even Russian), others only have the occasional visitor. So chances questions in those languages getting to be answered are rather very low – and we certainly don't aim at collecting unanswered questions.
- Don't argue one could use some online translator – that argument doesn't count. I'd compare it to a question consisting only of a link ("This is what I want to ask"), which we clearly close as a question should be self-contained (as answers should). So asking to follow a link is disregarded – all the more should it be asking all visitors to use some translation service just to understand the question.

**TL;DR:** Either translate it yourselves, or close as unclear with a comment so OP can translate (and we can reopen afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you were prompted by [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/67161/como-optimizar-imagenes-en-mi-pagina-web-how-to-optimize-images-on-my-website) recent question.

With new users, I have been being kind and running their questions through Google translate. Of course, they would then have to Google translate any answers.

I don't really have an opinion either way. I suppose that if anyone has time, it is nice to try to help. But I might not be so lenient with anyone who has some rep on any S.E sites, who ought to know better.